# Why is the trace map from a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ continuous?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $k$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$. Why is $tr_{k/\mathbb{Q}_{p}}$ a continuous map from $k$ onto $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: You need to put together a few facts, but this shouldn't be so bad. What's your favorite definition of the trace?

Comment: The key fact here is that the trace map is linear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Show that a $\mathbb Q_p$-linear map $f:V\to W$ of finite dimensional $\mathbb Q_p$-vector spaces is always continuous. What you want then follows from $\mathbb Q_p$-linearity of the trace, which is more or less immediate.